# Blender stops responding when importing object

Tags: import

Whenever I import an object file larger than a GB or so blender stops responding and will eventually just close. I've tried leaving it on for hours on end and it still crashes. The file I want to import is roughly 3GB or so. It's a part of my minecraft server and probably has millions of triangles or something. Is there a way to get it to work or should I try to find a way to reduce the file further? It gives no error logs when it crashes. Closest thing I got was something similar to not enough memory. Sorry if it's a dumb question or has been asked before. I could'nt find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. 16GB is just not enough. I got it down to an 800mb file and my computer is just on fire trying to keep up with it all.